# What determines if a function is blocking?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using OkHttp to make a synchronous get request. To avoid blocking the main thread, I wrapped the blocking network call in a suspend function and `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`

```
    suspend fun run(): String {
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
            .build()
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
            return@withContext response.body!!.string()
        }
    }
```

Android Studio gives me the warning "Inappropriate blocking method call" for both the `execute()` and `string()` functions. I would expect `execute()` to be blocking since it is making a synchronous http request. I do not understand why `string()` would be considered blocking, since it is just retrieving a property from a variable. How does Kotlin determine which functions are blocking and which are not?

Comment: [The documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/string/) says that `string()` loads the response body into the memory, maybe that is the blocking part. I may be wrong.

Comment: I think it mostly just looks at whether the function as defined in Java `throws IOException`. The compiler’s blocking method detection is very rudimentary and inaccurate, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the suspended fun run() inside a coroutine for it to work. You are probably calling it with variable = run(). And it is expecting a return, but the return is not ready. So it blocks awaiting for the return.